# chrome doesn't maximize when running selenium testNG from jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing a problem with running

> selenium testNG

test from jenkins , the problem is that i am doing a login to my application and checking some element visibility , when i run the test from the batch file directly i got a success because i'm setting my google chrome driver to maximize using:

> driver.manage().window().maximize();

but if the browser is minimized some elements are not visible (front-end requirements) , so when i run the test from `jenkins` the test failed because i think that the browser doesn't maximized ,

can someone correct for me if i'm wrong , and some help of how to maximize the browser when running from jenkins?

Comment: maximizing should make no difference to locating elements

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg i'm locating element by id ,ex:(if the button is not showing on the browser because of minimize lets say it doesn't work) my question to you is selenium works with coordinates (x,y) ?

Answer (score 1):

When you run your Selenium Suite from jenkins to particular server then `driver.manage().window().maximize()` doesnt work sometime. Thats why the preferred way is to go by usinn options depending on the browser you are using.

Eg:- 
For MAC or Linux:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--kiosk");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

For Windows:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

You can try with this, it will work using jenkins

Answer (score 0):

As per [manage().window().maximize() method not maximize a correct window](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=596) using `driver.manage().window().maximize();` to maximize the `Chrome Browser` is not the optimum way. Instead use **ChromeOptions** to maximize the *Chrome Browser* as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

As an alternative you can also use the argument **`window-size`** as follows:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("window-size=1400,600");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: i've also tried options.addArguments("start-maximized"); but it works only when i run the batch file directly but from jenkins still not working

Comment: @elie Checkout my answer update and let me know the the status

Comment: thank you for your concern, i tried it and still the same , works from batch directly but fail from jenkins ,i've used dm = driver.manage().window().getSize(); to get width and still = 1044 not changing

Comment: @elie When you set `window-size=1400,600` what do you get in return through `driver.manage().window().getSize();`?

Comment: @ DebanjanB i got this : (1044, 600)

Comment: So thats perfect right? Set your `window-size` accordingly through `ChromeOptions` and `addArguments` as per the alternative within my answer.

Comment: @ DebanjanB actually only height is being changed not the width , while what i need to change is the width not the height. i've tried to set  window-size=1400,650 i got (1044, 650) .

Answer (score 0):

Were facing the same kind of problem and solved using this snippet: (Java)

driver.manage().window().fullscreen();

It started failing, then passed arguments to reduce the font size for the contents displayed in screen.

```
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extenstions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0.75");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("high-dpi-support=0.75");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem,

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
```

is not enough,

I also use this

```
chromeOptions.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0.75");
```