# Jenkins don't open window of browser in fullsize

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a problem with CI Jenkins. On the local machine test build without problem.

When I try build my test-case in the Jenkins the window of browser don't open fullsize.[image]

[image]

On this reason WebDriver can't find some element. In the first time I'm use `driver.manage().window().maximize();` - this is don't help me. After I correct on

```
                ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
                chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

It also did not help me.

Comment: Alternatively, you can try to [Run Selenium Tests in Headless Browser](https://www.built.io/blog/run-selenium-tests-in-headless-browser)

Comment: Yes it works. But this is not a solution to my problem. I have to use exactly chromedriver

Comment: It means you want to view the test steps getting executed ?

Comment: You can view and try the solutions in these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772879/chrome-doesnt-maximize-when-running-selenium-testng-from-jenkins https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715927/unable-to-maximize-browser-when-running-through-jenkins-as-windows-service?lq=1